# $productAttribute->getSource() is throwing an error in admin grid

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, object

The line $productAttribute->getSource() in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Grid.php throws an error: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object

This is the concerning function

```
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
    $productAttribute->getSource();
    $this->addColumn($productAttribute->getAttributeCode(), array(
        'header'    => $productAttribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
        'index'     => $productAttribute->getAttributeCode(),
        'type'      => $productAttribute->getSourceModel() ? 'options' : 'number',
        'options'   => $productAttribute->getSourceModel() ? $this->getOptions($attribute) : ''
    ));
}
```

I assume a certain attribute didn't get created and this is causing the issue. But how can I debug it, find out which attribute is causing the issue? I tried to var_dump $attributes and $productAttribute but that results in a blank page. Nothing in log files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

    $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();

    if(!is_object($productAttribute))
       Mage::log($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());

    $productAttribute->getSource();
    ...
}
```

And then check your log file to see which one is causing the error.